# the existence of density preserving map

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random varible defined on the probability space $(R^n,F; P)$, $Y$ be a random varible defined on the probability space $(R^m,F; P)(m<n)$, does there exist a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that density of X equals to the density of $Y$, if have, how to prove?

I think such a map exists, but I don't know how to prove. From the definition of density, $p(x)= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2h} P(x-h<x<x+h) (x\in R^n)$, where $ P(x-h<x<x+h)$ is estimate with the proportion of sample falling in the interval(x-h,x+h). Assume the number of samples is fixed, then $p(x) \propto \textrm{nuber of points in this inerval} (x-h,x+h)$. I think there exist a injective map form interval $(x-h, x+h)s$ to the interval $(y-h', y+h')s(y \in R^m)$, if number of points in corresponding intervals are same, then the density of X and Y is same.

Comment: The density of $X$ and $Y$ can of course not be the same when $n\neq m$. Did you mean to ask if there exists a map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f(X)$ and $Y$ has the same density? (Note that writing $f:X\to Y$ does not make sense).

Comment: Yes, I mean if there exists a map $f:R^n \rightarrow R^m$ such that X and Y has the same density.

Comment: I think such a map exists, but I don,t know how to prove. From the definition of density, $p(x)= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2h} P(x-h<x<x+h) (x\in R^n)$, where $ P(x-h<x<x+h)$ is estimate with the proportion of sample falling in the interval(x-h,x+h). Assume the number of samples is fixed, then $p(x) \propto \textrm{nuber of points in this inerval} (x-h,x+h)$. I think there exist a injective map form interval $(x-h, x+h)s$ to the interval $(y-h', y+h')s(y \in R^m)$, if number of points in corresponding intervals are same, then the density of X and Y is same.